# Kubernetes status hang on Pending status

Tags: kubernetes

I tried multiple times and searched a lot but could not figure out why my pod is still in Pending status.

I have a very simple `docker-compose.yml` file as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build: .
    container_name: "something_cool"
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

and converted it to Kubernetes syntax with `kompose` command, so it created the two `deployment` and `service` files as below.

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: something-cool
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "80"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Now that when I run `kubectl apply -k .`, I see `service/nginx configured` and `deployment.apps/nginx configured`, but `kubectl get pods` shows it in Pending status.

This is the result of grepping pod name in events:

```
6s        Warning   FailedScheduling               pod/nginx-77546f7866-j5gmd              0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
4m4s        Warning   FailedScheduling               pod/nginx-77546f7866-j5gmd              0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
5m6s        Normal    SuccessfulCreate               replicaset/nginx-77546f7866             Created pod: nginx-77546f7866-j5gmd
```

If I'm correct, I see that I can ping and nslookup kubernetes.io fine, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: can you try "kubectl get events" too see if there is something in it that has an issue with scheduling? otherwise check your running pods in the kube-system namespace and check if scheduler pods are actually up and running

Comment: @meaningqo my last part of code in the question is the `FailedScheduling` reason

Comment: Did you just initialized this cluster ? Because if so, I ran into the same trouble after installing calico network. Calico required `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-` command to run in order to identify master from others. Maybe that is your problem ? Also, can you please check the other nodes that are unreachable as well, please.

Comment: @Catastrophe yes, I ran `kubeadm init` after installing K8S, and I run this code but still the same issue

Comment: What were your steps exactly ? What did you install as network?

Comment: @Catastrophe the issue was exactly I did not install any network, and now it's working and ready:) I reset with kubeadm and init it with network pod

Comment: Without changing anything ? Thats odd. But congratz :)

Comment: @Catastrophe no, I did `kubeadm reset`, then removed the config file from `.kube` folder, then run `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`, then `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml` and finally `kubectl apply -k .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the issue first by resetting the Kubernetes by the below ways:

1. `kubeadm reset`
2. `rm ~/.kube/config`
3. `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`
4. `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`
5. `kubectl apply -k .`